# OpenEmbedded: root account doesn't exist!

Tags: configuration, root, busybox, glibc, accounts

I'm using the current OpenEmbedded system from: http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/

(For what it's worth, I'm also pulling in layers from http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/ and http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-xilinx/tree/.)

I have built up a set of recipes and a distro (adapting from an older set of recipes which worked with OpenEmbedded from a couple of years ago), which boots like this:

```
...
[    2.441070] EXT3-fs (ram0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    2.450891] EXT2-fs (ram0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    2.466262] EXT4-fs (ram0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.474002] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 1:0.
[    2.480845] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.484107] Freeing unused kernel memory: 200K (c066f000 - c06a1000)
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[    3.200537] EXT4-fs (ram0): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
bootlogd: cannot allocate pseudo tty: No such file or directory
[    3.341168] random: dd urandom read with 9 bits of entropy available
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
chown: unknown user/group root:root
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
Configuring network interfaces... ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
ifconfig: SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
Starting Dropbear SSH server: dropbear.
Starting HOSTAP Daemon: nl80211 not found.
Starting syslogd/klogd: done
Starting tcf-agent: OK

MYDISTRO 0.1 zc706-zynq7 /dev/ttyPS0

zc706-zynq7 login: [    8.338466] macb e000b000.ps7-ethernet eth0: link up (1000/Full)
zc706-zynq7 login: root
Password:
Login incorrect
zc706-zynq7 login:
```

(Never mind the "No such device" errors - I can fix that later.)

The problem here is that the usual login method of username="root" (password not even requested) doesn't work. **It appears the root user doesn't even exist here!** Any expected password for root (such as empty, "root", "admin", etc) doesn't work. I can't get into this system.

After doing some trial and error debugging, I changed my conf/distro/mydistro.conf to comment out these lines:

```
...
# The following features are required by eglibc for a clean build of the sdk.
#DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC = "libc-libm libc-backtrace libc-spawn libc-locale-code libc-getlogin libc-posix-regexp libc-ftraverse libc-posix-clang-wchar libc-posix-wchar-io libc-inet libc-crypt libc-nsswitch libc-utmp"
#DISTRO_FEATURES = "ext4 usbhost wifi pci ipv4 ipv6 largefile ${DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC}"
```

**which causes the default DISTRO_FEATURES to be used from http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/conf/distro/include/default-distrovars.inc** (which is included from http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/conf/distro/defaultsetup.conf, which in turn is included by http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf on line 682).

Now it boots like this:

```
[    2.446482] EXT3-fs (ram0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    2.456386] EXT2-fs (ram0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    2.471774] EXT4-fs (ram0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.479516] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 1:0.
[    2.486308] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.489626] Freeing unused kernel memory: 200K (c066f000 - c06a1000)
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[    3.203046] EXT4-fs (ram0): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
bootlogd: cannot allocate pseudo tty: No such file or directory
[    3.345494] random: dd urandom read with 8 bits of entropy available
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
Configuring network interfaces... ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
ifconfig: SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
Starting Dropbear SSH server: dropbear.
Starting HOSTAP Daemon: nl80211 not found.
Starting syslogd/klogd: done
Starting tcf-agent: OK

MYDISTRO 0.1 zc706-zynq7 /dev/ttyPS0

zc706-zynq7 login: [    8.348120] macb e000b000.ps7-ethernet eth0: link up (1000/Full)
zc706-zynq7 login: root
root@zc706-zynq7:~#
```

Yay, the root account works!

The question is now: **what is the key missing DISTRO_FEATURE that makes the root account work?**